# div column in select MySQL query not working with replace into

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some code like this:

```
REPLACE INTO digisob_rekap_peruser(
    user_rk,
    lokasi_lk,
    target_lk,
    pertarget //2. data does not enter this column ,
    vis_lk,
    nsb_lk)
SELECT
    jadwal_userid,
    lokasi_lk,
    target_kunjungan*$x,
    vis_lk/target_lk*100 AS pertarge //1. this line,
    COUNT(jadwal_userid) AS total,
    SUM(SJ_Tsel_3_2) AS jualan
FROM
    jadwal,
    data_kunjungan,
    user,
    digisob_rekap_peruser
WHERE
```

Number 1 has a result but this result does not enter the column in number 2.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE digisob_rekap_peruser`? In your select statement you need to `JOIN` rather than comma separated. Show the full `SELECT` query  and its results - if this is empty its not surprising it doesn't get inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default data types for your percentage calculation is likley causing the data loss.

You need to cast the values to decimals/floats/doubles etc to handle it.

```
select 1/10
-- 0
select 1/10 * 100
-- 0
select cast(1 as decimal)/cast(10 as decimal)
-- 0.1000000000000000000
select cast(1 as decimal)/cast(10 as decimal) * 100
-- 10.0000000000000000
select cast(cast(1 as decimal)/cast(10 as decimal) * 100 as int)
-- 10
select cast(cast(cast(1 as decimal)/cast(10 as decimal) * 100 as int) as varchar(4)) + '%'
-- 10%
```